# Migrate server with Clonezilla to larger disk

Tags: partitioning, migration, clonezilla

I have a virtual Ubuntu server with a 40 GB hdd. I used Clonezilla and created an disk image of that server. The reason I want to clone it is because of disk space (I need more). The other server is in a HP Blade Center, so it's a phisicial one with a 200 GB disk.

**When I restore the image to the new server it only restores the 40 GB, it didn't expand the disk.** I have also tried with the Clonezilla Advanced mode where I used the '-k' and '-r' options to create the partition table proportionally in the target disk and resize the file system in the partition automatically. But that din't solve my problem.

Do you know any way of how can the image be restored so that I have all the 200GB? Or do you even know a better way that Clonezilla to do this migration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a partioning tool like GParted, which comes preinstalled with the live media and resize the partition. GParted should find the right partition table type and file system type, expand the partition and apply the right command to resize the file system.

You could also do this from terminal with e.g. `parted` and `resize2fs` (for the default install) from another Linux installation or live media (you cannot resize the root file system online as far as I know), but doing it from the live media with GParted should be the easiest way.

Comment: I have done it with the GParted live cd, and when I'm in the GParted tool it shows me everything as I want. As soon as I boot the system it shows the old partitioning..

Comment: You need to apply the operations via the menu (Edit -> Apply All Operations) or the checkmark icon in the toolbar.

Comment: I have done that. The thing was that I had to use lvextend and resize2fs after booting back into the system. Thank you for the answers.

Comment: You should have added to your question that you are running LVM.